# Convert string of numbers to list of numbers

Tags: python, string, list, split

```
l='2,3,4,5,6'
```

expecting:

```
[2,3,4,5,6]
```

In python how can I convert into the above format

the first one is a string of some numbers I am expecting a list of same numbers.

Comment: try this l.split(“,”)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As simple as this:

in Python2:

```
print [int(s) for s in l.split(',')]
```

and in Python3 simply wrapped with a parentheses:

```
print([int(s) for s in l.split(',')])
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
l='2,3,4,5,6'

result = [int(i) for i in l.split(',')]
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

The above is equivalent to the following `for` loop:

```
result = []
for i in l.split(','):
    result.append(i)
```

As an alternative you could use [map](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map):

```
l = '2,3,4,5,6'
result = list(map(int, l.split(',')))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this simple and direct way with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
list_of_numbers = [int(i) for i in l.split(",")]
```

Alternatively, you can fix up the string so it becomes a "list of strings", and use `literal_eval`:

```
import ast
s = "[" + l + "]'
list_of_numbers = ast.literal_eval(s)
```

Comment: You have a typo: `"]'` => `"]"`

Answer (score 2):

you can use [map](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/map_filter.html#map) and [split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) to convert.

```
map(int, l.split(','))
```

Example:

```
l='2,3,4,5,6'
print(map(int, l.split(',')))
```

output

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use map like this:

```
list(map(int,[i for i in l if i.isdigit()]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given: `l='2,3,4,5,6'`

Lazy way: `output=eval('['+l+']')`

Lazy way with Python 3.6+ (using fStrings): `output=eval(f"[{l}]")`